# tkinter not importable from terminal but works in Python 3 shell on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, terminal, mplayer

Thank you for your help in advance I've been stuck for nearly a week now!

I am trying to use tkinter on my Pi and the following works ok when run in the python application (shell):

```
import tkinter
tk = tkinter.Tk()
window = tkinter.Tk()
tk.mainloop
```

However when I enter the command:

```
python /home/pi/myfiles/windowtest.py
```

in the terminal, I get

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

So far I have tried sudo apt-get install tkinter, same with updates, dev, tk, -f, python-tkinter and any others I could think of. 
In fact `sudo apt-get install tkinter` is unable to locate the package and the same with `python-tkinter`.

`sudo apt-get install python-tk` tells me is already the newest version installed.

Im using the latest NOOBS installed it about 10 days ago.

Background - I want to run a bit of python script started by crontab that uses mplayer, at the moment all the mplay blurb pushes my menu off the screen in terminal mode and I can't see it. I was hoping tkinter would open a window in which I can put my menu into and see it.

Comment: Are you running Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Raspberry PI, Python 3, although I do have Python 2 installed too which I could try using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the module is named `Tkinter` in Python 2 and `tkinter` in Python 3. In Debian, Raspbian, Ubuntu and so forth, `python`  on command line starts Python 2.x (usually 2.7 by now) whereas `python3` is needed to run the Python 3.x interpreter.

As this is a new project I guess you should only use Python 3 (and you have written your code for Python 3), thus run the command with **`python3`**:

```
python3 /home/pi/myfiles/windowtest.py
```

---

```
% python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
>>> import Tkinter
>>>
```

vs

```
% python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the responce, however I'm not using the PC. Everything I'm trying to do  is on the PI. I'm using Python 3 on the PI please continue to help!

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a simple answer that I have been searching for and using too much of my brain power thinking about. I can sleep easy tonight. Next I need to figure how to get crontab to run it so I can see the windows.

Comment: Notice that if you are using crontab, you need to explicitly set the DISPLAY=:0 environment variable so that it knows on what display to run... and if you think I solved your problem then please tick my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Thank  you crontab for another day now. Yours solution has worked perfectly, I tested it already. Thank you so much . .  .

Answer (score 0):

Run the script with:

```
python3 main.py
```